# Задачка по Питону

Tags: python

Есть задача, в в аргумент `sys.argv` приходит число (предположим `865` ).
Как написать код, что бы он это число плюсовал друг к другу (`865 = 8+6+5`).

Уже всю голову сломал.

Текст задачи:

> ```
> import sys 
> digit_string = sys.argv
> ```
>
> В переменной `digit_string` будет
>   содержаться строка `“865”` (ну или какая-то другая строка,
>   сгенерированная нами, в том числе другой длины). В строке, подаваемой
>   на вход, будут только символы, соответствующие цифрам от 0 до 9.
>
> В результате ваша программа должна напечатать на экран сумму цифр (для
>   строки `“873”` сумма будет `18`).
>
> В списке sys.argv будут лежать аргументы командной строки, sys.argv -
>   имя запущенного файла, sys.argv - строка, сумму цифр которой
>   необходимо посчитать и вывести на экран

Подскажите пожалуйста, не получается.

Comment: "уже всю голову сломал текст задачи" - Вам непонятен текст задачи?

Comment: Можно, например, использовать замечательный метод `list()` и немного подумав как именно его использовать, написать код и если что-то не будет работать - спросить тут :)

Comment: Да, увы непонятнет :/

Comment: Пожалуйста, не меняйте ваш вопрос, когда уже появились ответы. Вы можете добавить что-то, но остальные участники должны видеть связь между вопросом и ответами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print(sum(map(int, sys.argv[1])))
```

Comment: Для обучающих целей, полагаю, было бы неплохо показать пример с использованием `eval`: ```print(eval('+'.join(sys.argv[1])))```, - а также пояснить почему ваш вариант лучше и безопаснее. Это бы избавило от множества прочих вопросов.

Comment: @gregzakharov для обучающих целей вопрос надо закрыть, а как использовать `eval` нельзя показывать никогда и ни за что.

Comment: показывать то как раз нужно, дабы у вопрошающих в последствии было четкое представление того как не нужно писать код. А что до закрытия темы, это даже не обсуждается, ибо это даже на вопрос не тянет.

Comment: Так короче и понятнее: 
     sum(int(n) for n in str(x))

Comment: Строку не надо превращать в список! В этом её интересное отличие от. Точнее, отличие `map()` и `filter()` от list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 873
s = 0

while x > 0:
    s += x % 10
    x //= 10

print(s)  # 18
```